# Carregar o valor do state no componentDidMount formatado por moeda

Tags: javascript, react, jsx

Estou querendo carregar um valor definido no `state` da aplicação.
Usando um lib para formatar o input e colocar mascara de moeda formato Real (`react-intl-currency-input`).

Só que ele não carrega o valor no input quando aplicamos o `componentDidMount`.

Vejam:

```
this.state = {
   salario: '1800.00'
}

<IntlCurrencyInput
   currency="BRL"
   config={currencyConfig}
   onChange={this.handleChangeSalarioFormato}
   id="salario"
   value={this.props.salario}
   placeholder="Salário"
   disabled={this.state.disabled}
   className="form-control"
 />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passa o valor inicial na propriedade `defaultValue` do componente `<IntlCurrencyInput>`. Depois trata a alteração do valor na tua função `handleChangeSalarioFormato`:

```
<IntlCurrencyInput
   currency="BRL"
   config={currencyConfig}
   onChange={this.handleChangeSalarioFormato}
   id="salario"
   defaultValue={this.props.salario}
   placeholder="Salário"
   disabled={this.state.disabled}
   className="form-control"
 />
```